# mysql new table with repeated columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have one table with the rows:
id, vehicle, start_date, finish_date

and one table with the rows:
vehicle, decel,accel,corner,vert,eventcode,eventdate.

Im trying to create a new table pulling data from both these tables, where the vehicle is the same in each table, the event date in table2 is between the startdate and finishdate from table1.

I have the code:

```
CREATE TABLE new_event_data SELECT * from table1, table2
where table1.vehicle=table2.vehicle
and table2.eventdate BETWEEN table1.start_date AND table1.finish_date
```

This results in a new with the columns:
decel, accel,corner,vert,eventcode.
All the repeated columns such as vehicle, and the event date columns are ignored.
Is there anyway of getting the dates in the new date so the data from both tables can be correlated? 
Im trying to group the events into one table.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to run this and you will get a duplicate column name error (on vehicle) - you need to apply aliases for duplicate names. You should also specify all columns rather than is * and use an explicit join rather than the outmoded implicit join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alias names and specify all the columns names in your select query, like below--

Here, Table1 alias is A, and column A_C1 is first column name of table1.

`CREATE TABLE new_event_data SELECT A.A_C1,B.B_C1,... from table1 A, table2 B
where A.vehicle=B.vehicle
and B.eventdate BETWEEN A.start_date AND B.finish_date`